setting stem color in musixtex
For kits it is needed to setting stem color in musixtex (lets say black). The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{\color{black}I \color{black}II \color{black}III \color{black}IV \color{black}V \color{black}VI \color{black}VII \color{black}I}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\setsongraise1{-4mm}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
\def\raisebarno{6\internote}%
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\B\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}
%\addspace{-\afterruleskip}%
\NOTEs\zq{c}{\color{blue}\zq{e}}{\color{gray}\qu{g}}\color{black}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{d}}{\color{cyan}\zq{f}}{\color{teal}\qu{h}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{e}}{\color{gray}\zq{g}}{\color{green}\qu{i}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{teal}\zq{h}}{\color{cyan}\zq{f}}\qu{j}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{k}}{\color{green}\zq{i}}{\color{gray}\ql{g}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{l}}\zq{j}{\color{teal}\ql{h}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{k}}{\color{cyan}\zq{m}}{\color{green}\ql{i}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{l}}{\color{gray}\zq{n}}\ql{j}\en
%\addspace{-1.5\afterruleskip}%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

Note that when we configure the color to notehead, it also change the color of stem. So we need a command to set the color of steam.

Have you tried anything yourself, e.g. with a black note with stem and a colored head on the same place? As a recorder teacher I do not agree that it would be necessary to work with colors for children.

In fact you applied what I suggested - without referring to my comment, but you did it in a strange way: working with an offset is a matter of trial and error, while in this case working with a non-spacing note is more MusixTeX:
{\color{black}\zqu{g}}{\color{gray}\nq g}


Solved:
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{\color{black}I \color{black}II \color{black}III \color{black}IV \color{black}V \color{black}VI \color{black}VII \color{black}I}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\setsongraise1{-4mm}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
\def\raisebarno{6\internote}%
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\B\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}
%\addspace{-\afterruleskip}%
\NOTEs\zq{c}{\color{blue}\zq{e}}{\color{black}\qu{g}}{\color{gray}\loffset{6.695}{\zq{g}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{d}}{\color{cyan}\zq{f}}{\color{black}\qu{h}}{\color{teal}\loffset{6.73}{\zq{h}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{e}}{\color{gray}\zq{g}}{\color{black}\qu{i}}{\color{green}\loffset{6.73}{\zq{i}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{teal}\zq{h}}{\color{cyan}\zq{f}}\qu{j}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{k}}{\color{green}\zq{i}}{\color{black}\ql{g}}{\color{gray}\loffset{6.68}{\zq{g}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{l}}\zq{j}{\color{black}\ql{h}}{\color{teal}\loffset{6.67}{\zq{h}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{red}\zq{k}}{\color{cyan}\zq{m}}{\color{black}\ql{i}}{\color{green}\loffset{6.67}{\zq{i}}}\en
\NOTEs{\color{blue}\zq{l}}{\color{gray}\zq{n}}\ql{j}\en
%\addspace{-1.5\afterruleskip}%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The solved output is as follow:

